# Cannot use the crosstab of a non-fixed column as a subquery. (Error 3637)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

When creating a report, I can run the record source and get the desired tables, but when I go back to report design and click anything other than design view I get:

> Cannot use the crosstab of a non-fixed column as a subquery. (Error
>   3637)

My report needs to take a bunch of dates, employees, and hours worked from tables, and group all of the Jan/Feb/.../Dec dates together and shows how many hours that employee worked that month. This report should be a big table with Dates on top and employees on the left. I am new to Access and very confused on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone receiving this error, you have to separately save the subquery.